# What's the equivalent schema datatype for java.util.Set?

Tags: java, set, graphql

I am using GraphQL for Java and need to use Set / HashSet datatype for one of the member of my existing POJO to build by GraphQL schema. Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Comment: Unclear what your asking. Which version of Java are you using? This is the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) for Set interaface in Java 10. Check out the `All Known Implementing Classes` part.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in set type in GraphQL , sorry about that.

What you get the closest one is `List` type which is represented by enclosing any types using `[` and `]` such as `[String]` , `[Int]` , `[Bar]` etc. It can accept multiple elements but does not guarantee uniqueness between the containing elements.

You may consider to implement a [directive](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/draft/#sec-Language.Directives) for a set behaviour. May be called `@set` which is placed along with the list data type when defining your GraphQL schema.